Does vim-gtk support stylistic sets and texture healing?
I've installed Monaspace on my Mint system (21.3, Cinnamon edition), and selected it for use in gvim (8.2.2121). However, texture healing isn't working and ligatures don't look right.
I have the following settings:
set guifont=Monaspace\ Neon
set guiligatures=!\"#$%&()*+-./:<=>?@[]^_{\|~}

(I also had renderoptions=type:directx, but I had another look at the docs and realised this option only applies to Windows.)
I note that slashes and some other characters do look different under the cursor, which is a known bug, apparently to do with ligatures, so perhaps they're trying to work. The same bug report implies that ligatures work with at least some versions of Gvim, for some fonts. So, should texture healing and ligatures work for Monaspace, under GTK Gvim, or do I need to do more setup?
I don't see any reference to ligatures in Gvim 9's release notes, but is there a reason to think they might work better in a more recent release?
And finally, how can I select the various stylistic sets that Monaspace talks about, or are these the same as the 'feature tags' that are currently not supported in Gvim?

Îm afraid you have reached the limits of what Vim can do with fonts.

There is already an issue regarding calt opened 6 years ago, to which you even participated last year. No need to crosspost: if you want things to happen, make them happen over there.

@romainl: Ah, yes, well spotted. I hadn't remembered getting quite that far, when I tried this on my old system. But before posting on GitHub about it this time, I wanted to make sure I wasn't just doing it wrong, and since user questions didn't seem to be encouraged on GitHub, I posted here. It seems you're confirming that I wasn't, and I appreciate that.
